# Conditional Excel formatting based on another cells value

Tags: excel

I want to take a cell and format it based on the value of another cell. For example

I want to from A23 based on the value of C23 but when I select A23 and ass this formula it only formats D23. Also is there a way to duplicated this easily for 29 other rows? A22/D22 for example.

```
="D23<1%"
```

Comment: What '29 other rows'? It helps if you are specific about things like cell and worksheet references. Is that formula really trying to compare the value to a text string that looks like a formula or are the quotes a typo and it is supposed to be `=D23<0.01`?

Answer (score 0):

Select all of the cells you want to apply the conditional formatting rule to with the cell in the top-left as the active cell. Note the row of this cell. For the sake of argument, I'll say this is row 22.

Clear out the previous attempts at a conditional formatting rule and start a new one. Choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* then supply the following in the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box.

```
=$D22<0.01
```

Note that I've used row 22 in this formula. That should be changed to whatever row your block of cells to receive the CF rule starts with.

Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and select some formatting. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to confirm the formatting choices and then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule.